# How to get Windows text resource from current display language

Tags: c#, localization

If Windows is set to a non-English display language, certain UI elements in Windows also change (e.g. MessageBoxButtons appear in the selected display language). Is there any way to get those text resources and integrate into my .Net application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a repository for localized common text in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663855/is-there-a-repository-for-localized-common-text-in-winforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes you could. The Windows [common controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) retrieve localized strings for the relevant language using MUI files in %WINDIR%\System32{LocaleIdentifier}. There is an [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that shows how you can do the same in win32. So you could in load localized strings from comctl32.dll.mui and comdlg32.dll.mui using the same IDs as the Windows controls though [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx). But this wouldn't be pretty, could cause breaks in future updates of Windows (it's private data, with no promise that it won't change) and would frankly seem overkill.  It's much easier and safer to maintain your own set of localized strings!