# Get system localized strings

Tags: c#, winapi, locale

I have done custom message box for my app,but I wish to localize my OK/Cancel, Retry/Ignore button just like the message box does. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a repository for localized common text in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663855/is-there-a-repository-for-localized-common-text-in-winforms)