# System defined text for button in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, button, text

I was wondering if there are system-defined text-values for buttons in C#.

Let's say, I want to make some default buttons ( like those for `MessageBox` ) that uses system-defined text like "Save", "Close" and so on.

The idea behind this is, that I have language dependent buttons in my MessageBoxes and Open/SaveFileDialoges, but not in my main window.

So my application has following buttons: "Save", "Open", "Clear", "Close".

My System Language is German, so those buttons in the main form are still in englisch but the buttons for e.g. `MessageBox.YesNoCancel` are "Ja", "Nein", "Abbrechen" ( the german Version ).

So my question: Is there a way of applying system-defined text for buttons like this ? ->

```
myCancelButton.text = SystemButtons.Cancel;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a repository for localized common text in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663855/is-there-a-repository-for-localized-common-text-in-winforms)

Comment: But there is no SystemButtons?

Comment: @Crono oh okay, didn't found it. thx

Comment: @Blam this was only an example.